# Players $A$ and $B$ play a chess tournament, what is the probability that $A$ wins?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Two chess players $A$ and $B$ play a tournament. A tournament is a sequence of games, each of which is independent from the rest. There are three different results from a game: player $A$ wins (1), the game is a draw (1/2), player $B$ wins (0). Based on some rating of the players known before the start of the tournament, it is known that

- player $A$ wins with probability $a$,
- the result is a draw with probability $b$, and
- player $B$ wins with probability $c$.

These probabilities are not affected by the games. As usual, $0\le a,b,c\le 1$ and $a+b+c=1$.

Now, the first player to win two games (not necessarily in a row), wins the tournament; draws do not count. A tournament does not have a limit on the number of games (notice that if $b=1$ the tournament will go on forever, all games ending in a draw). For example, in the sequence of games

- $(1,1)$ player $A$ wins the tournament since the only two games played were won by $A$,
- $(1,0,1)$ (and in any permutation of this sequence of games) player $A$ wins the tournament, and player $B$ has won only one game.
- $(1,1/2,\dots,1/2,1)$ player $A$ wins the tournament because $A$ won the first and last games and the other were draws,
- $(0,0,1)$ it is player $B$ who wins this tournament.

**QUESTION** What is the probability that player $A$ wins a tournament (as a function of $a$, $b$ and $c$)?

I first tried tackling this problem by calculating the probability that a given sequence of results can happen. So, for player $A$ to win the tournament, only the three following scenarios can happen,

- ($i$ draws) (B wins once) ($j$ draws) (A wins once) ($k$ draws) (A wins once)
- ($k$ draws) (A wins once) ($i$ draws) (B wins once) ($j$ draws) (A wins once)
- ($i$ draws) (A wins once) ($j$ draws) (A wins once)

where $i,j,k\ge 0$ are integers (not necessarily equal among all scenarios). My limitation here is that I don't know what the values of $i$, $j$ and $k$ can be. Even if I knew, I'm not sure what to do with the probabilities of each scenario. I'm not good at probabilities, and I really don't know where to even begin. I thought formalizing things with Bernoulli or Geometric random variables would help, but I haven't had any result that matches the computer simulations. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let denote $P(i,B,j,A,k,A)$ the probabilities like you described above, I would think that the ratio between something like $P(i,B,j,A,k,A)$ and $P(i,A,j,B,k,A)$ is the same as the ratio between $P(i',B,j',A,k',A)$ and $P(i',A,j',B,k',A)$ so it suffices to compute the probabilities for $i=j=k=0$.

Comment: As an aside, I find it amusing that the probability that $A$ wins is $a$, but the probability that $B$ wins is not $b$. More to the point, assuming $b<1$, you can entirely remove draws from the picture by replacing $a$ with $\frac{a}{1-b}$ and $c$ with $\frac{c}{1-b}$. This corresponds to changing the definition of "a game" to mean that they keep playing until one of them wins.

Comment: The main complication is the draws which can be dealt with by considering the probability that $A$ wins given that it's not a draw and applying Bayes' theorem. With a little squinting you'll see that's exactly what @Arthur has done.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, these were my exact thoughts when I first read the statement haha. I'll think about the rest tomorrow. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer. I hope it's correct. The goal is to compute the value

$$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{A wins tournament}) =
\frac{\sum \text{probabilities events in which A wins tournament}}{\sum  \text{probabilities all events in which one of A or B wins tournament}}
\end{equation*}
$$

To ease this task, it was suggested in the comments of OP to change the definition of winning a game to exclude draws as a possibility. For this, we calculate the conditional probability that $A$ (resp. $B$) wins assuming that the game is not a draw using Bayes' theorem
$$
\begin{align*}
P_A &= \mathbb{P}( \text{A wins} | \text{the game is not a draw} ) \\
    &= \frac{\text{Probability of A winning and the game is not a draw}}{\text{The game is not a draw}}\\
    &= \frac{a}{1 - b} \\
    &= \frac{a}{a + c}
\end{align*}
$$
For $B$,
$$
\begin{align*}
P_B &= \mathbb{P}( \text{B wins} | \text{the game is not a draw} ) \\
    &= \frac{c}{1 - b} \\
    &= \frac{c}{a + c}
\end{align*}
$$
Under this new definition of game (where draws are excluded), consider the events in which one of the two players wins the tournament:

- (1) BAA  ($B$ wins one game, then $A$ wins two games)
- (1) ABA  (first $A$ wins a game, then $B$ wins, finally $A$ wins the second game and the tournament)
- (1) AA   ($A$ wins twice, $B$ does not win)
- (2) ABB, BAB, BB

The probabilities of the events where $A$ or $B$ win are, respectively,
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{(1) } e_A &= 2P_BP_A^2 + P_A^2 \\
\text{(2) } e_B &= 2P_AP_B^2 + P_B^2
\end{align*}
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{A wins tournament})
= \frac{e_A}{e_A + e_B}
= \frac{a^2(b - 2c + 1)}{b(a^2 + c^2) - 2a^2c - 2ac^2 - a^2 - c^2}
= \frac{a^2(3c + a)}{(a + c)^3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Draws occurring do not affect the number of wins (or who does win), therefore we can eliminate them altogether (we consider draw events as non-existent and focus on the relative win probabilities of $A$ vs $B$).  The  probability that $A$ wins the next non-draw   game is $\frac{a}{a+c}$, the probability that $B$ wins is $\frac{c}{a+c}$. The sequencess of wins which results in $A$ winning are:
$$A,A\\
A,B,A\\
B,A,A$$

These events have a total probability of:
$$(\frac{a}{a+c})^2 + 2 (\frac{c}{a+c})(\frac{a}{a+c})(\frac{a}{a+c})= \\
=   (\frac{a}{a+c})^2 (1+\frac{2c}{a+c})$$

Comment: Notice, $a/(1 - b) = a/(a + c)$, and $c/(1 - b)=c/(a + c)$ by definition $a+b+c=1$. What I fail to see is how your result is exactly the same as [mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4535841/746100) without considering the total probabilities of one of the two players winning. Could you make your answer a bit more original by explaining this, please? I mean, your answer is almost a copy of mine but in the first probabilities you give the denominator in $a+c$, and you skip the last step in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I just glanced at the end expression and saw that it was too complicated (you've since edited the answer to simplify it). Therefore I gave a simpler expression. What you should consider in a proper exclusion of the draw is not $P(\text{A wins the next game})$ but $P(\text{the first future game that does not end in a draw is won by A})$ . This gives a sequence $p = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ab^n = \frac{a}{1-b} = \frac{a}{a+c}$. Which coincides with the naive probability obtained by eliminating $b$ and considering the relative probabilities of $a$ and $c$.

Comment: Yes, I typically make quite a few changes after posting an answer. It might be very true that it went from being complicated to being simpler. Also, thanks for the reminder of the formula $p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ab^n$ (I tend to forget about it). But, what about the last step where I do the $e_A/(e_A + e_B)$ and you simply claim that the sought-after probability is simply $e_A$? Could you elaborate that a bit, please? I don't have (complete) formal training in mathematics/probability and some things just go completely over my head. Thanks!

Comment: The probability of a draw is $0$ if $b<1$ . So either $A$ wins or $B$ wins. In short, $e_A + e_ B = 1$.

Comment: You're right. Haha! Lord. Sorry to have bothered you for such a thing. I should've checked!